# Apache drill query on mongo collection failing with error "Can't find a codec for class com.mongodb.DBRef"

Tags: mongodb, apache-drill

Drill queries on collections from a Mongo database fail whenever there are DBRef fields present in collection items, regardless of the query.

For `phones` collection with an example item inside:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("e14323e54c51fa3"),
    "customer" : DBRef("Customer", ObjectId("3e56a45f2324a")),
    "phone" : "123142312"
}
```

the query

```
SELECT * FROM phones LIMIT 1;
```

results in

```
Error: SYSTEM ERROR: CodecConfigurationException: Can't find a codec for class com.mongodb.DBRef.
```

If a collection does not contain items with DBRefs everything works as expected. Any idea how to work around this would be appreciated.

Comment: This can be raised as an issue on Drill-jira

Comment: what version is this (of mongod, java driver, drill, etc)

Comment: @AsyaKamsky Drill 1.3 (did not work on 1.0+), mongo 2.6 and 3.1

Comment: what version of Java driver?  Or is that what 3.1 references?

Comment: @AsyaKamsky yes, my apologies, Java driver 3.1

Comment: Have a look on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31827635/resolve-dbref-into-json